# Value of unassigned non-nullable variable (C#)

Tags: c#, non-nullable, unassigned-variable

Just curious.

If you go:

```
string myString;
```

Its value is null.

But if you go:

```
int myInt;
```

What is the value of this variable in C#?

Thanks

David

Comment: A simple test would be enough for you to answer this yourself.

Comment: I think the quality of the answers has proven the value of the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Firstly, note that this is only applicable for fields, not local variables - those can't be read until they've been assigned, at least within C#. In fact the CLR initializes stack frames to 0 if you have an appropriate flag set - which I believe it is by default. It's rarely observable though - you have to go through some grotty hacks.

The default value of `int` is 0 - and for any type, it's essentially the value represented by a bit pattern full of zeroes. For a value type this is the equivalent of calling the parameterless constructor, and for a reference type this is null.

Basically the CLR wipes the memory clean with zeroes.

This is also the value given by `default(SomeType)` for any type.

Comment: and +1 for the field/variable distinction

Comment: When I wrote the question I meant local variable rather than field, but since I was unaware of the distinction in this regard I didn't make that clear.

I didn't know that int fields were initialised at zero - thanks for that info.

Answer (score 5):

default of int is 0

Answer (score 5):

The default value for int is 0.

See here for the full list of default values per type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is a table of default values for value types in C#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx
Reference types default value is usually null.

Answer (score 2):

String is a reference type. Int is a value type. Reference types are simply a pointer on the stack directed at the heap, which may or may not contain a value. A value type is just the value on the stack, but it must always be set to something.

Answer (score 1):

The value for an unitialized variable of type `T` is always `default(T)`. For all reference types this is null, and for the value types see the link that @Blorgbeard posted (or write some code to check it).