# C# lifetime of a variable in try finally

Tags: c#, try-catch

i got the following code

[image: screenshot]

why has x in the finally-block the value 5 instead of beeing "already defined" or having the default value 0?

Comment: That's funny, the debugger indeed shows 1. You can't _use_ `x` in the finally block though, `finally { int x; int y = x; }` won't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have set a breakpoint in the `finally` and looked at `x`. `x` has no value according to the C# language spec but the debugger probably looked at the storage location that the first `x` had and showed you its value.

In real code you would be unable to read from `x` in the `finally`.

The debugger does not obey the rules of the language.

Answer (score 7):

The lifetime of `x` is within `{...}` block, `try` in your case; however, since there's no *zero-initialization* of *local variables* in .Net the next `x` contains *trash* which is former `x` value

```
try
{
   int x = 5;
}
finally
{
   // x is re-declared; since x is local it contains trash;
   // former x was aquired at the stack, so .Net just moves stack pointer 
   // and doesn't remove former x value
   int x; 
   ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691170(v=vs.71).aspx

...A local variable *is not automatically initialized* and thus *has no default value*...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742(v=vs.71).aspx

...The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration *is the block in which the declaration occurs*...

Comment: Do you have a reference from MSDN stating that local variables are not initialized. I thought the `JIT` uses `default()`, but the compiler enforces initialization to avoid bad code.

Comment: they have a default value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929257/value-of-unassigned-non-nullable-variable-c (see Skeet's answer)

Comment: @fubo: a *quote* from the answer: "for fields, *not local variables - those can't be read until they've been assigned*... value of `int` is 0..."
italic is mine (Dmitry Bychenko). Note, that *local variables* (unlike *fields*) are *not initialized* by zeros

Answer (score 1):

You *probably* use visual studio debugger, that relays on variable names for values watch, and some how shows wrong value, in such messed up cases.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of variable `x` is limited to `try` block only,
yes Debugger shows the value 5 but 
if you try to use `x` variable you will face the problems you mentioned.

Try This:

```
finally
{
   int x;
   Console.Write(x); //error use of unassigned local variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why has x in the finally-block the value 1 instead of being "already
>   defined" or having the default value 0?

What you are seeing is the debugger linking up the symbols.  It doesn't have a value at all, and in fact if you try and use it you get an unassigned variable error.

Now why doesn't it show as already defined is another question. The answer is that the `{}` define the declaration space.  (In C# variables are defined at the branch level, not the function level).   They are in two different declaration spaces and that's why it is allowed.  The first `x` can't spill into where the second `x` is defined.

What you have is different than

```
void foo () {
 var x = 2;

 if (true){
   var x = 3;
 }

}
```

Which isn't allowed.